# How to use JavaScript client condition to exec PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, client-server

I have some function that needs to be executed on the client (like screen size), but I want to display some things in PHP based in the result of the JavaScript scripts.

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $_GET['var1']; ?>
    <script>
      if (1 > 2)
      {
        <?php echo "$_GET['var2']; ?>
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want is to synchronously verify some things in JavaScript and based on that result continue the execution of the PHP

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: php is compiled before javascript in server side. then  javascript is compile din browser! so you can not do this

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki You're right but maybe existe a way to exec a part of PHP, then call website with JS functions a redirect to the rest of the PHP. What do you think abou it?

Comment: you may want to look into AJAX

Comment: Yes, But this is not what you showed in your code! you can not execute php code with javascript code (after page load), but you can redirect the page with js after page load to a php page : `window.location = "http://www.example.com/my.php"`